# When an invertible element in a $C^{*}$-algebra is unitary

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

I am trying to show that if $a$ is an invertible element of a unital $C^{*}$-algebra, and $||a||=||a^{-1}||=1$, then $a$ is unitary. I can do this if I think of $a$ as a Hilbert space operator using Gelfand-Naimark. I think it can be done without using Gelfand-Naimark but I haven't been able to do it so this is what I would like to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a result in $C^*$-algebras that if $b$ satisfies $b = b^*$ and $\sigma(b) \subset [\alpha,\beta]$ where $\alpha,\beta > 0$, then $\alpha I \le b \le \beta I$?

Then you could prove it as follows.  Consider $b = a^* a$.  Then a short argument shows that $\|b\| = \|b^{-1}\| = 1$.  But $b$ is positive, and $\inf\sigma(b) = \sup\sigma(b) = 1$.  Hence $I \le b \le I$.  Therefore $b=I$.

Comment: +1. I think the minimal $C^*$-tool required here is Gelfand: if $b$ is normal then the (commutative) $C^*$-algebra $C^*(b)$ generated by $b$ is $*$-isometric to $C(\sigma(b))$ where $b$ is identified with $f(t)=t$. This yields what you claim in the first paragraph. Also, what you call a short argument is what makes a $C^*$-algebra a $C^*$-algebra, namely $\|x^*x\|=\|x\|^2$ for every element.